# Hough Transform on a live feed using OpenCV

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I have been trying to find out how to apply the Hough Transform on a web cam feed. However I am getting the error that it does not have the appropriate format, even though I gray scaled it an checked to see if it was in uint8.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.medianBlur(frame,5)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    ###
    #HughCircles Detection TEST  
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(frame,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,50,
                               param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0) 
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    if circles is None:
        for i in circles[0,:]:
            # draw the outer circle
            cv2.circle(frame,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
            # draw the center of the circle
            cv2.circle(frame,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
    #    
    ###

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Board',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: you should probably compute on `gray`, not `frame`

Comment: Lol, instant facepalm tks @Miki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, looking at another post I saw that circles actually return None when there is nothing visible so there has to be an if so that it doesn't refer to None.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.medianBlur(frame,5)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

###
#HughCircles Detection TEST  
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,50,
                          param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0) 
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    if circles != None:
        for i in circles[0,:]:
        # draw the outer circle
            cv2.circle(gray,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
        # draw the center of the circle
            cv2.circle(gray,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
#    
###

# Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Board',gray)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: Post the correct code in the answer, and not in the original question, otherwise is impossible understand what the problem was

Comment: Don't correct the code in the question! Post the correct code in the answer, and mark yours as an answer.

Comment: I rollback-ed the question with the non-working code. Edit the correct code into the answer

Comment: There's no rush, but seems you got it :D. Mark this as the answer when you can.